# Kotlin to override protobuf types toString

Tags: protocol-buffers, kotlin

Suppose we have some data classes which are generated with `protoc`.

Google's `toString()` sucks for multiple reasons, it's not very human-readable, and even puts line breaks in representation which screws up logs and many tools that don't expect multiline log.

So the problem is: how do we redefine custom toString() for a class like that?

I've tried to override (or maybe hide?) original `toString()` with an extension function like this

```
fun Messages.DataClass.toString(): String {
    return "some custom logic"
}
```

but it won't pick up the extended function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to change the implementation of an existing method in a class using Kotlin. An instance method defined in a class always takes priority over an extension function with the same signature.